# How do I get cookies in the background of a firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to firefox addons, and was wondering how I could make simple commands with cookies; get, set, add, delete. The important thing is I need to run this in the background, without the webpage I want cookies from open.

The code I am currently using in my main.js looks like this:

```
popup.port.on("getCookies", function () {
    var {Cu} = require("chrome");
    Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
    var cookieService = Services.cookies;
    console.log(cookieService.getCookiesFromHost('google.com'));
});
```

However, it only prints the cookies when I have www.google.com open. What method can I use for the add-on to retrieve cookies in the background?

Comment: You're on the right track. `Services.cookies` is the way to go, now you just need documentation on how to use it. The docs are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieManager2

Comment: Yes, like shown above, I used the getCookiesFromHost() function in the console.log(). However, it always returns {} on the sdk, unless I open the domain where I want cookies from.

Comment: Do you use `cfx run`? If yes, then please note that this will always create a new profile, where there are no cookies initially, of course. This might explain why `getCookiesFromHost` does not return anything until you open the page: There are simply no cookies before that (for any host) ;)

Comment: My bad, should have noticed that. Yeah, I use cfx run. Is there any way to modify the browser automatically on startup (e.g. have firebug installed)? Thanks!

Comment: You can run `cfx` specifying a profile, so it would reuse that one all the time. Use the `-p` flag and set a name that would be the folder of your profile. For example `cfx run -p ~/devprofile` will create a clean profile in your home directory (linux and osx), then you can install firebug and quit, and execute again with the same profile specified: you will find firebug in the installed add-on.